# php mysql generate unique where statement for particular row

Tags: php, mysql

Lets take a TABLE (table) for example

```
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
| col1 |  col2  |   col3    |  col4 |
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
|  11  |  text1 | long text |   g   |
|  22  |  text2 | long text |   5   |
|  11  |  text1 | long text |   x   |
|  44  |  textx | long text |   0   |
.... thousands of rows... 
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

I want to create a php function, say- unique_statement(...)  which automatically generates a unique statement for MYSQL WHERE clause for each row

```
function unique_statement($table_name,$row)
{ // code
   return $statement;
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
{
  echo '<a href="?WHERE='.unique_statement('table',$row).'">EDIT</a>'.$row['col1'].' etc...';
}
```

So that on user request, i can simply show form to edit that particular row

```
$GET_['WHERE'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['WHERE']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $GET_['WHERE']");
// rest code to show that particular row for editing...
```

I can create my own statement to select any particular table, but problem is that i have multiple tables, whose column type is arbitrary(number, varchar, text, datetime, etc..) and table may have unique or primary index or may not have any index.

So, to generalize my code to edit data for each table i need to create a function which automatically generates unique statement for each row for SELECT WHERE clause.

I tried much but failed write that function... i want some function which mysql data manager (like phpmyadmin, adminer, sqlbuddy) uses to identify each row. Please HELP ...

Comment: ... are you implying that none of your tables have primary keys? O_o

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_GET` data never goes directly in a query.

Comment: @CD001 some of tables have index and some of them have no index.

Comment: @tadman i knew all that, this is just a test code to show my problem. anyway I've edited and added one more line to my test code....

Comment: "Test code" has a way of working its way into production when you're not looking. Please don't ever do this for any reason. The risk of a mistake is way, way too high. Using placeholder values is considerably  safer and easier. The way you're escaping things here is extremely error-prone. One slip and your entire application can be cracked open.

Comment: @agaggi **every** table should (in almost all instances) have a PRIMARY key - even if that primary key is just an auto-incremented unsigned INT called `id` - that way if you ever need to reference any record you can do so using the primary key; it gives you that unique atomic reference point you're after.

Comment: @CD001 you are definitely right, every table should have PRIMARY key. but in my case few of those tables have no primary key even no index, and that is where my problem appears to create statement for selecting particular row. If this would have one table i could have written it manually but if there are many tables with no index no fix structure/column, i need some solution which automatically creates a statement to put in MYSQL WHERE clause... any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: @agaggi is the data in each row unique? (you could try adding a `UNIQUE` key that includes every column if you can't alter the table structure to add an `id` column) - if so, it would be really messy, but you could, in your SQL select something like `SHA1(CONCAT(table.col1, table.col2, table.col3, table.col4)) AS id` which would give you a 40 character unique identifier for that particular record (you're unlikely to get any collisions unless you've got tens of millions of rows).